# pxssh- Could not login to the server with special characters in the password

Tags: python, pxssh

When I try to login to a remote server with special characters in the password, it throws a `'Password Refused'` error. However, it works for the password without special characters.

My code:

```
import pxssh

s = pxssh.pxssh()
s.login('mylabserver4.com', 'testuser', 'Tes123P@ss')
```

But, I am getting `'Password refused'` error even though the password is correct.

How do I get the code to accept special characters?

Answer (score 0):

Try escaping special character `@` with `\`

`s.login('mylabserver4.com', 'testuser', 'Tes123P\@ss')`

Ideal way should be to ask for the user prompt as per the documentation as well:

> http://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pxssh.html#pexpect.pxssh.pxssh

```
from pexpect import pxssh
import getpass
try:
    s = pxssh.pxssh()
    hostname = raw_input('hostname: ')
    username = raw_input('username: ')
    password = getpass.getpass('password: ')
```